# French accent into align environment with htlatex

Tags: align, accents, tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax

I am using first `latex` compiler to generate pdf document. Into `.tex` source, I have the following equation :

```
\begin{align}
\text{tenseur sym\'etrique :}\,\,\,\,& S_{ij}=(1/2)\,(T_{ij}+T_{ji}) \notag \\
\text{tenseur antisym\'etrique :}\,\,\,\,& A_{ij}=(1/2)\,(T_{ij}-T_{ji})
\label{exo4117}
\end{align}
```

That generates this rendering :

[image: Latex rendering]

Now, I tried to generate HTML pages with MathJax using `htlatex` compiler and I get the following result :

[image: Htlatex rendering]

As you can see, the french accent is not taken into account. I suspect the `\text{...}` to be implied in this issue.

How can I circumvent this problem and produce this MathJax equation with french accent (like I did with `latex` compiler) ? Any suggestion is welcome.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that MathJax doesn't support TeX accents in math text. You can just use accented characters directly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \text{tenseur symétrique :}\,\,\,\,& S_{ij}=(1/2)\,(T_{ij}+T_{ji}) \notag \\
  \text{tenseur antisymétrique :}\,\,\,\,& A_{ij}=(1/2)\,(T_{ij}-T_{ji})
  \label{exo4117}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

To request good support for accented characters, it seems necessary to use

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    mtextFontInherit: true
  }
})
```

as a configuration for MathJax. Full configuration file for tex4ht:

```
\RequirePackage{mathjax-latex-4ht}
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{\unexpanded{<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
        TeX: {Macros : {  mathlarger: ["{\\large \#1}",1] }},
        "HTML-CSS": { mtextFontInherit: true }
});</script>}}}
\EndPreamble
```

It is rendered in this way:

[image]